# How do I disable Window Hello from appearing on the Lock Screen

Tags: windows-10, biometrics, windows-hello

Even when not enabling Windows Hello in Sign-In Options, the camera will still film you and display an annoying animation and the message that you have to set up a PIN. How to remove Windows Hello completely?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Run gpedit.msc (Edit group policy in Control Center)
2. Navigate to Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates >
   Windows Components > Biometrics
3. Disable "Allow users to log on using
   biometrics" (or "Allow the use of biometrics")

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the PIN if you've already set one up.  Then the next time you sign in, notice how the prompt says something like 'sign-in to setup Windows Hello'.  Change that to a normal password or fingerprint sign-in by clicking the icon below the password field.  That did it for me.  Now I can sign-in without being forced to enter a new PIN. :-)

Answer (score 0):

#### For Windows Home Edition users

For those that don't have Windows Pro, the equivalent solution is to set the registry value  `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Biometrics\Enabled` to `0` (hex). If it doesn't exist, create the key as type `dword (32 bit)` in the `Biometrics` folder.