# How evade "Your account requires a Windows Hello PIN"?

Tags: windows

I got new Windows laptop.  I don't want PIN! How skip this screen below?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Easier than the disabling instructions below is simply to set the PIN to be the same as your password. Then you're not lowering your security in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disconnect from the internet (unplug the ethernet cable or turn off wifi) when you get to this screen and then click "Create PIN" and it will fail. You can reconnect the internet after it fails and setup continues.

**Update:**

After windows has been set up you will need to disable "Windows Hello" or it will prompt you to set up a pin when the computer locks. [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1349173/216046)  describes the process for disabling the pin requirement (Win 10 Pro required):

1. Run gpedit.msc.
2. Select Local Computer Policy / Computer Configuration / Administrative Templates / Windows Components / Windows Hello for Business
3. Set the "Use Windows Hello for Business" policy to Disabled, and click "Apply"
4. Reboot

Answer (score 0):

If you do not connect to the internet while setup, this screen does not come. Also if you use a local account you can use Password.

After you create PIN, you can switch your login method to password later by Settings app > Accounts > Sign-In options > Under PIN click Remove and again click Remove.

Comment: There is no Remove as of October 2020.

Comment: @thesmart As of 30/11/2023, Disable 'Require Windows Hello for Sign-In for Microsoft Accounts', and you will get the remove option.